# how to tell DST if server on UTC

Tags: c#, timezone, dst

My Windows web application server is set at UTC so there is no indication of DST or not on the timezone selection UI. So when my c# code is running on that server, `DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime()` always returns False. Is there a way to check to see if a particular time zone (i.e. Eastern Time) is currently in DST or not?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` is evil, and should *never* be used in server-side code.  Read more in my blog post on this subject: [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).  With careful coding, your code should not care what the time zone setting of the server is.

You are looking for this:

```
TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
bool dst = tz.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
```

Don't let the string `"Eastern Standard Time"` fool you - that is the `TimeZoneInfo.Id` for the US Eastern time zone, encompassing both Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight Time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of all time zones with `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`.  It returns a collection of type `TimeZoneInfo`.  When you find the right one, it has a property `SupportsDaylightSavingTime` to tell you if it uses DST at all.

After that, you can call `IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime)` to see if DST is in effect for a given date.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And what is the "DateTime" specifically in the call of `IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime)` ?

Comment: @Niner It's the date you want to check.  If you want to know if DST is currently in effect, pass `DateTime.Now`

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin - Close, but actually you need to pass `DateTime.UtcNow`.  Passing `DateTime.Now` in the first segment of a DST fall-back transition will be translated wrong.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks, I hadn't considered that.